# Rename a modifier's name for multiple objects

Tags: modifiers

I have multiple objects and they have the same exact modifier with same name (same parameters , name etc). For example :

- cube1 has modifiers : array1, **boolean1**
- sphere1 has modifiers : solidify1, **boolean1**
- cone1 has modifiers : **boolean1**

So i want to change the name of **boolean1** to become **myboolean** for multiple objects at once. Can i do this ?

Do we need python for this ? using <kbd>Alt</kbd> doesn't do the trick for multiple edit.

Thanks

Comment: Yes most likely you need to use Python to do that.

Comment: Well if modifier is expected to have all parameters the same then you can rename it for one object and then use any facility to copy it over to other objects (Link modifiers or Copy Attributes addons etc). However to just do renaming this won't be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over all objects (or all **selected** objects, in the following script). If the object supports modifiers, check if the looked for modifier name exists, if it does, rename it.

```
import bpy

previous_name_modifier = "boolean1"
new_name_modifier = "MyBoolean"

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if not obj.modifiers:
        continue
    mod = obj.modifiers.get(previous_name_modifier)
    if mod:
        mod.name = new_name_modifier
```